# Using python M2Crypto AES cipher with java

Tags: java, python, openssl, aes, m2crypto

I have the following python code:

```
def AES_build_cipher(key, iv, op):
   return EVP.Cipher(alg='aes_128_cbc', key=key, iv=iv, op=op, padding=True) # PKCS#5 paddig

def AES_encrypt(key, msg, iv): # key, iv -> bytes, msg -> text
   if iv is None:
       raise ValueError("IV must be defined!")

  # Return the encryption function
   def encrypt(data):
       cipher = AES_build_cipher(key, iv, ENCRYPTION)
       v = cipher.update(data)
       v = v + cipher.final()
       del cipher
       return v

   return encrypt(msg)
```

It works ok (encryption/decryption via M2Crypto).

Java code for decryption:

```
public static String AESDecrypt(String b64data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws CipherException {
    try {
        aesCipher_ = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCipher_.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        final byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(b64data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        final byte[] decryptedData = aesCipher_.doFinal(byteData);

        return new String(decryptedData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CipherException(e);
    }
}
```

data:

- iv = 8b9123ba6712612fb98452aac3854838 (hex representation)
- text = 12345678901234567890 (simple text)
- ciphertext =
  af87d97bf9779efcff0386d4eaee18619dc8f1fe7c5adea2a91657f53491bc2 (hex
  representation)
- password = 791a06ee369dc2f842c655f6bec8ce2 (hex representation)

Result:

- Exp:'12345678901234567890'
- Got:'1���$V��c�J�}7890'

Looks like something wrong with IV (first 16 bytes of result). But I have no idea what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was be with IV in python. It's actually will be unicode string, not ascii string.
The following code will help convert unicode str to ascii str:

```
''.join([chr(ord(x)) for x in request.session['iv']])
```